# Set Linking.getInitialUrl to be null

Tags: javascript, react-native, deep-linking

Linking.getInitialUrl is being called everytime the component reloads hence want the initial url to be set null manually.

The scenarios is when i logout login, the screen is navigated again, as the app stack component mounts again.

Comment: Please present better your issue, add some code and explain what you trying to do.

Comment: Can i manually set the initial URL to be null after it has been executed once? Becoz after logouy login it again receives the url and navigates.

Answer (score 0):

Set a global variable to the store (redux/context/zustand etc) like the following,

`isInitialRouteVisited = false`

Then change the value to **true** after visiting the first time. and recheck if it tries to revisit.